# Is it possible to animate flexbox inserts, removes, and item position?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, css-animations, flexbox

[This question was originally asked back in 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106876/is-it-possible-to-animate-flexbox-inserts-removes) however the answers provide did not cover the use case I'm interested in (smooth movement for wrapped content changing lines).

> "When I remove an item from a flexbox, the remaining items "snap" into
>   their new positions immediately rather than animating.
>
> Conceptually, since the items are changing their positions, I would
>   expect the transitions to apply.
>
> I have set the transition property on all involved elements (the
>   flexbox and the children)
>
> Is there any way to animate edits (adds & deletes) to a flexbox?"

I'm particularly interested in animating movement of flexbox items that are wrapped to other rows/columns.

The desired end functionality would resemble what is available [in metafizzy's isotope.](http://isotope.metafizzy.co)

Comment: possible duplicate of [is it possible to animate flexbox inserts & removes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106876/is-it-possible-to-animate-flexbox-inserts-removes)

Comment: @BrettDeWoody The OP specifically links this question and states it is dating from 2012 ...

Comment: The solution (posted on July 26,2014) is included with that question.

Comment: True, but that solution doesn't cover or solve for the use case I mentioned, where the elements are wrapped to more than one line.

Answer (score 2):

I could do it, and it's a litle tricky 
https://codepen.io/balvin/pen/wXGyYw

Without wrap, it's easier https://codepen.io/balvin/pen/gKrXdM
basically yo need to set all your flex items to `width:0;flex-grow:1`
but when you want it to work with wrap it becomes a little harder because the items need to have `width` in order to be avaible to wrap them, so with some setTimeout I can acomplish that

Comment: Hi John, I have a similar CSS transition question here. If you know the answer, I'd really appreciate it! https://stackoverflow.com/q/67185337/470749

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no (or at least not yet). Flex-order is in fact animatable, because it would go one position at a time between your desired positions, in the given timeframe, but you will not get that smooth translation of elements.