# CSS transition upon insertion of element into flexbox WITHOUT adding/removing CSS class

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Let's assume I don't have access to JavaScript and can only edit CSS.

I still should be able to define a transition such that when JS (that I don't control) inserts a new element into a flex container the container widens smoothly, right?

```js
// For the purposes this demo (to make it useful for my actual challenge), 
// the only "allowed" JS is JS that adds or deletes an item within the container.

function insertOrDeleteExtraElement() { 
  const div = document.getElementById("new");
  if (div) {
     div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
  } else {
     const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
     newDiv.innerHTML = "Inserting or deleting this should transition the container's width smoothly, honoring the transition duration.";
     newDiv.id = "new";
     document.getElementById("container").appendChild(newDiv);
  }
}
```

```css
#container {
  border: 2px dashed blue;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 250px;
  transition: all 1s;
}
input {
  flex: 1 1 100px;
  transition: all 1s;
}
#new {
    flex: 1 1 100%;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 120px;
    transition: all 1s;
}
.old {
    background: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="insertOrDeleteExtraElement();" style="font-size: 16px;">Click here</button>
<br/>
<div id="container">
  <input type="text" value="old input" class="old"/>
  <div class="old">old div</div>
</div>
```

**How can I accomplish my goal with only CSS (no JavaScript or HTML changes)?**

Similar questions in years past (such as [Is it possible to animate flexbox inserts, removes, and item position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28822760/is-it-possible-to-animate-flexbox-inserts-removes-and-item-position?noredirect=1&lq=1)) have collected answers about how to define CSS transitions, but they all required JavaScript to add or remove class names of an element.

To clarify: I don't want JavaScript manipulating classList of any existing element. The only allowed JavaScript would be the actual insertion of a *new* element into the flexbox container, such as in my example here.

P.S. Also, I need the new element to be on its own line, which is why I'm using `flex-wrap: wrap;`.

Comment: it can be done for insertion but not the deletion

Answer (score 1):

You can do like below for the insertion. I doubt you will have luck with the deletion since CSS cannot the remove event to do something before.

```js
// For the purposes this demo (to make it useful for my actual challenge), 
// the only "allowed" JS is JS that adds or deletes an item within the container.

function insertOrDeleteExtraElement() { 
  const div = document.getElementById("new");
  if (div) {
     div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
  } else {
     const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
     newDiv.innerHTML = "Inserting or deleting this should transition the container's width smoothly, honoring the transition duration.";
     newDiv.id = "new";
     document.getElementById("container").appendChild(newDiv);
  }
}
```

```css
#container {
  border: 2px dashed blue;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 250px;
  transition: all 1s;
}
input {
  flex: 1 1 100px;
  transition: all 1s;
}
.old {
    background: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#new {
    flex: 1 1 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
    animation:grow 1s forwards;
    
    height:0;
    flex-basis:0;
    min-width:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
@keyframes grow {
  to {
    height:120px;
    flex-basis:100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="insertOrDeleteExtraElement();" style="font-size: 16px;">Click here</button>
<br/>
<div id="container">
  <input type="text" value="old input" class="old"/>
  <div class="old">old div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. What I was trying to ask for is how to create a smooth transition of the *widening* of the container (and therefore widening of the old input). +1 anyway because I really appreciate the effort! Thanks.