# css trasition reposition child div flexbox

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, flexbox

[image: select animation gif]

https://jsfiddle.net/v4nqrwzv/      FIDDLE

As shown in the above gif animation, I have an slight jerking motion after the icon is selected. The icons are placed inside a container div with a fixed width and are spaced out evenly with `flexbox`. When a user makes a selection the icons un selected will scale down to .1 and then go to `display: none`. However, the remaining icon is repositioned in a jerking movement. How can i make this reposition smooth? Each icon has a transition of all 1s ease. and the containing div has a transition on the width as well so that i could make the width auto. Here is some code:

**css:**

```
.select-type--selections{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  width:520px;
  transition: width 1s ease;
}

.select--outline{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 60%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 15px;
  @include card(1);
  transition: box-shadow .5s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1), 
    transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1), 
    opacity 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
 }
.material-out-transition{
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}

.material-out-enter, .material-out-leave{
  transform: scale(.1);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

**html:**

```
<div v-show="section=='select'" class="create--select-type">
    <h1>Select Task Type</h1>
    <div class="select-type--selections">
        <div v-for="(key, val) in taskType" v-show="val" transition="material-out" @click="makeSelect(key)" class="select--outline">
            <img class="option--icon" :src="'/assets/image/' + key + '.svg'" alt="edit task">
            <p class="outline--text">{{key}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: I added a fiddle with example

Answer (score 0):

With some help from [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106876/is-it-possible-to-animate-flexbox-inserts-removes) I was able to come up with [this solution](https://jsfiddle.net/Aides/7ns39oyz/1/).

I feel like there might be a better solution than this but maybe this will do.

(If you need fixed sized content you could use what I created as a wrapper for fixed-sized parent-centered content).

```
.icon
{
    //...
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.icon.hidden
{
    flex-grow: 0.00001; //setting to 0 breaks the transition
    width: 0px;
}
```

Be aware that you must not set the div to `display: none` before the animation has ended.

Answer (score 0):

try with this below code it may help you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.icon').click(function(){
    $('.icon').not(this).css('display', 'none');
  });
});
```

```css
.container{
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: no wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.icon{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
  border-radius : 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #888888;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.iconFormat{
 font-size : 20px;
 padding : 15px;
 color : #888888;
}
div.icon:hover{
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px #888888;
}
div.icon>span{
display : none;
padding-top : 10px;
color : #888888;
}
div.icon:hover span{
display : block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o iconFormat"></i><span>Reading</span></div>
  <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-pencil iconFormat"></i><span>Writing</span></div>
  <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-music iconFormat"></i><span>Music</span></div>
  <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-film iconFormat"></i><span>Movie</span></div>
</div>
```