# How to animate elements inserted and removed in NativeScript's FlexboxLayout?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm trying to have a row of buttons that grow and shrink depending on if other buttons are added or removed. `FlexboxLayout` seems most appropriate for this job, but I can't seem to figure out how to approach the problem other than manually manipulating the width percentages over a time.

I thought I could set `flexGrow` on them and then use a class with `visibility: collapse` to essentially remove buttons. (And then reverse when returned to normal.) This works, but the change is pretty instantaneous. I would like some sort of squishing/stretching animation.

I tried playing with animations, shrinking the scale to 0 like below. Though the button appeared to shrink, it only did toward the center of itself and still held the space it took up (leaving a gap).

I'm playing with a simple example like this:

```
<FlexboxLayout flexDirection="row">
  <Button text="1" width="25%" flexGrow="1"></Button>
  <Button text="2" width="25%" id="test-button"></Button>
  <Button text="3" width="25%" flexGrow="1"></Button>
  <Button text="4" width="25%" flexGrow="1"></Button>
</FlexboxLayout>
```

And I tried doing something like this, where I want to shrink button #2 to gone:

```
let testButton = this.page.getViewById("test-button");
testButton.animate({
  scale: { x: 0, y: 1},
  duration: 500
});
```

I also tried to do it with keyframes. That seemed to not do anything.

```
#test-button {
  animation-name: shrink;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}


@keyframes shrink {
    from { width: 25%; }
    to { width: 0; }
}
```

I tried to do something like what was mentioned [in this answer here for web pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106876/is-it-possible-to-animate-flexbox-inserts-removes), but that also didn't seem to do anything.

I managed to get it to work by using databinding that manually adjusts the width using `setTimeout`. But I was wondering if there might be a different route that might be a bit easier to manage? Can't help but wonder if maybe I'm botching something in my other attempts.

Answer (score 5):

You could hide the Button, while using button  `visibility` property and to hide the component, when the animation finished. For your convenience I am attaching sample code

app.component.html

```
<FlexboxLayout flexDirection="row">
  <Button backgroundColor="green" text="1" width="25%" flexGrow="1"></Button>
  <Button backgroundColor="blue" (loaded)="buttonLoaded()" text="2" width="25%" id="test-button"></Button>
  <Button backgroundColor="green" text="3" width="25%" flexGrow="1"></Button>
  <Button backgroundColor="blue" text="4" width="25%" flexGrow="1"></Button>
</FlexboxLayout>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Page } from "ui/page"

@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    templateUrl: "app.component.html",
})
export class AppComponent {

    constructor(private page:Page){}

    public buttonLoaded(){
        let testButton = this.page.getViewById("test-button");
            testButton.animate({
            scale: { x: 0, y: 1},
            duration: 500
        })
        .then(()=>{
            let testButton = this.page.getViewById("test-button");
            testButton.visibility='collapse'
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh hey, that's a way to do it! I appreciate the convenient code, too! :D Thank you. The only thing is, it's still more of an instant snapping with setting visibility to collapse. I'm not sure if I kind of like this way just as well though, since it still is pretty cool.

For the sake of the originally intended idea though, where the other elements would animated-ly grow into the opening space, do you think that's something only data bindings could do? The way I pulled it off with data bindings was to shrink the one button, and then those other buttons would grow with the shrinking.

Comment: This method also DOES NOT remove the item in an animated or linear way, rather hides the element and then suddenly snaps everything back, making everything look pretty damn ugly.

Comment: You explained it very nice and simple, thanks mate!