# How to hide a flexbox element with smoth effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to center divs and hide them on each click, the problem is when I use `hide()` and `flexbox` it makes a rude effect after dissapear, but if you just simply float elements to left it makes fine, how can I achieve this?

> I need to apply exactly the same disappearing effect that is in the
>   first example to the second one (with flexbox).

Here is the example:

```js
$(".example1, .example2").click(function(){
    $(this).hide("slow")
});
```

```css
.main{
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.example1{
  background-color: grey;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
}

.example2{
  background-color: grey;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 8px;
}
.second{
  border: 2px solid black;
  display:                 flex;
  display:                 -webkit-flex; 
  flex-wrap:               wrap;
  -webkit-flex-wrap:       wrap;        
  justify-content:         center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main"> 
With simple float left it hides slowly fine:
<div class="first">
    <div class="example1">1</div>
    <div class="example1">2</div>
    <div class="example1">3</div>
    <div class="example1">4</div>
    <div class="example1">5</div>
    <div class="example1">6</div>
    <div class="example1">7</div>
    <div class="example1">8</div>
    <div class="example1">9</div>
    <div class="example1">10</div>
    <div class="example1">11</div>
    <div class="example1">12</div>
    <div class="example1">12</div>
    <div class="example1">13</div>
<div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
Now flex center, when you hide it makes rude effect, it isnt like div.example1:
<div class="second">
    <div class="example2">1</div>
    <div class="example2">2</div>
    <div class="example2">3</div>
    <div class="example2">4</div>
    <div class="example2">5</div>
    <div class="example2">6</div>
    <div class="example2">7</div>
    <div class="example2">8</div>
    <div class="example2">9</div>
    <div class="example2">10</div>
    <div class="example2">11</div>
    <div class="example2">12</div>
    <div class="example2">13</div>
    <div class="example2">14</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The "rude" effect is the elements from the second row jumping into the first row as soon as there is enough space. This snaps the total width of the elements back to full width giving a bad visual effect. What effect would you like to have when the elements jump to the first row?

Comment: I don't think you can achieve this using `flex` and `hide()` - Here is a similar question that may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/24976134/5561605

Answer (score 5):

Use `flex-start` for `justify content` instead of `center`. Now it has the same effect as with `float`. You can also use `fadeOut` instead of `hide` to achieve effect you want.

```js
$(".example1, .example2").click(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut("slow")
});
```

```css
.main{
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.example1{
  background-color: grey;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
}

.example2{
  background-color: grey;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 8px;
}
.second{
  border: 2px solid black;
  display:                 flex;
  display:                 -webkit-flex; 
  flex-wrap:               wrap;
  -webkit-flex-wrap:       wrap;        
  justify-content:         center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main"> 
With simple float left it hides slowly fine:
<div class="first">
    <div class="example1">1</div>
    <div class="example1">2</div>
    <div class="example1">3</div>
    <div class="example1">4</div>
    <div class="example1">5</div>
    <div class="example1">6</div>
    <div class="example1">7</div>
    <div class="example1">8</div>
    <div class="example1">9</div>
    <div class="example1">10</div>
    <div class="example1">11</div>
    <div class="example1">12</div>
    <div class="example1">12</div>
    <div class="example1">13</div>
<div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
Now flex center, when you hide it makes rude effect, it isnt like div.example1:
<div class="second">
    <div class="example2">1</div>
    <div class="example2">2</div>
    <div class="example2">3</div>
    <div class="example2">4</div>
    <div class="example2">5</div>
    <div class="example2">6</div>
    <div class="example2">7</div>
    <div class="example2">8</div>
    <div class="example2">9</div>
    <div class="example2">10</div>
    <div class="example2">11</div>
    <div class="example2">12</div>
    <div class="example2">13</div>
    <div class="example2">14</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesnt center the divs.

Comment: @SilverSurfer So you want them centered and it has to be with flex or not ?

Comment: Yes, but whitout rude effect after dissapear

Comment: This is not a valid solution, I specified clearly this is not the desired effect.

Answer (score 4):

First, you can notice that this issue doesn't happen when you try to remove an item from the last row (excluding the first one in the last row). The issue appears when the first element of the row **n** suddenly go to the row **n-1** because of 2 things :

1. You are trying to remove this **first** element so its width is going to 0 then for sure he will be able to fit into the previous row.
2. You are trying to remove any element so its width is going to 0 and you are creating enough space for the first element of next row to jump on it.

And this is simply due to **center alignment** as there is no difference if you do it with float, inline-block or flex. What is happening is that during the transition all the elements are moving to the center and when the new element comes (the first one of the next row) all the elements are re-placed again to keep the center alignement and then you have the **rude effect** !

With left alignment all the elements will move to the left during the transition and they won't move again at the end of transition (when the new element comes) so we don't have any rude effect.

Here is a snippet that shows inline-block and flex working fine with left alignment :

```js
$(".example2, .example1").click(function() {
  $(this).hide("slow");
  
});
```

```css
.main {
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.example1 {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 8px;
  transition:margin 0.6s;
}
.example2 {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 8px;
  transition:margin 0.6s;
}
.first {
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.second {
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  inline-block 
  <div class="first">
    <div class="example1">1</div>
    <div class="example1">2</div>
    <div class="example1">3</div>
    <div class="example1">4</div>
    <div class="example1">5</div>
    <div class="example1">6</div>
    <div class="example1">7</div>
    <div class="example1">8</div>
    <div class="example1">9</div>
    <div class="example1">10</div>
    <div class="example1">11</div>
    <div class="example1">12</div>
    <div class="example1">13</div>
    <div class="example1">14</div>
    <div class="example1">15</div>
    <div class="example1">16</div>
    <div class="example1">17</div>
    <div class="example1">18</div>
    <div class="example1">19</div>
  </div>
   flex solution
  <div class="second">
    <div class="example2">1</div>
    <div class="example2">2</div>
    <div class="example2">3</div>
    <div class="example2">4</div>
    <div class="example2">5</div>
    <div class="example2">6</div>
    <div class="example2">7</div>
    <div class="example2">8</div>
    <div class="example2">9</div>
    <div class="example2">10</div>
    <div class="example2">11</div>
    <div class="example2">12</div>
    <div class="example2">13</div>
    <div class="example2">14</div>
    <div class="example2">15</div>
    <div class="example2">16</div>
    <div class="example2">17</div>
    <div class="example2">18</div>
    <div class="example2">19</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, I don't have a solution to this if you want to only use the `hide()` of jQuery. Maybe some *ideas* of solution is to make a more complex code that will avoid the centered elements to move in two directions (you may for example change margin property at the same time to cancel the movement) or you can keep the left alignment and find some trick to simulate the centering (dynamically add some margin when window resize for example).

Hope this will help you to investigate more (even if I didn't really give a solution).

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the above without `flex` by making the children `div's` as `inline-block` with the parent being set with `text-align:center`, please take a look at this.

```js
$(".example1, .example2").click(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut("slow");
});
```

```css
.main{
  border: 2px dotted black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.example1{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: steelblue;
  color: #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}

.first{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main"> 
<div class="first">
    <div class="example1">1</div>
    <div class="example1">2</div>
    <div class="example1">3</div>
    <div class="example1">4</div>
    <div class="example1">5</div>
    <div class="example1">6</div>
    <div class="example1">7</div>
    <div class="example1">8</div>
    <div class="example1">9</div>
    <div class="example1">10</div>
    <div class="example1">11</div>
    <div class="example1">12</div>
    <div class="example1">12</div>
    <div class="example1">13</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And with smoth effect like the first example?

Comment: I tried for smooth effect with transition, transform and with JS as well everything ends with ripple effect. So to solve your issue we need to compromise either with `float` and left alignment or with `fade` and the above transition.

Answer (score 2):

Well as pointed out already it would require some kind of "physics engine" moving the other blocks up smoothly etc.

But I made an attempt anyway which looks a bit more smooth at least.

```js
$(".example1, .example2").click(function(){
      var time = 600;
      var $parent = $(this).parent();
      $parent.animate({'width': '90%'}, time/2, function() {
           $parent.animate({'width': '100%'}, time/2);    
    });
    $(this).hide(time);    
});
```

```css
.main{
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.example1{
  background-color: grey;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
}

.example2{
  background-color: grey;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 8px;
}
.second{
  display:                 flex;
  display:                 -webkit-flex; 
  flex-wrap:               wrap;
  -webkit-flex-wrap:       wrap;        
  justify-content:         center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main"> 
<div class="second">
    <div class="example2">1</div>
    <div class="example2">2</div>
    <div class="example2">3</div>
    <div class="example2">4</div>
    <div class="example2">5</div>
    <div class="example2">6</div>
    <div class="example2">7</div>
    <div class="example2">8</div>
    <div class="example2">9</div>
    <div class="example2">10</div>
    <div class="example2">11</div>
    <div class="example2">12</div>
    <div class="example2">13</div>
    <div class="example2">14</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: looks better in a normal browser

Answer (score 0):

My idea is: fade the whole parent container during reordering.
The effect will not so rude.

```js
$(".second div").click(function() {
  $(this).hide("slow");
  var p = $(this).parent();
  p.addClass("hidden");
  setTimeout(function() {
    p.removeClass("hidden")
  }, 300);
});
```

```css
p {
  clear: both;
}

.second {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 2px solid black;
  transition: 200ms;
}

.second div {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="second">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
  <div>13</div>
  <div>14</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `justify-content: center` I changed it to `justify-content: space-evenly` (in your case, looks somewhat similar to center only) also updated the function from simply hiding to `.animate` and then `.hide`. Will it do?

```js
$(".example1, .example2").click(function(){
    var _this = this;
    $(_this).animate({width: "0"}, 500, function(){ $(_this).hide(500) })
});
```

```css
.main{
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.example1{
  background-color: grey;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
}

.example2{
  background-color: grey;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.second{
  border: 2px solid black;
  display:                 flex;
  display:                 -webkit-flex; 
  flex-wrap:               wrap;
  -webkit-flex-wrap:       wrap;        
  justify-content:         space-evenly;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main"> 
With simple float left it hides slowly fine:
<div class="first">
    <div class="example1">1</div>
    <div class="example1">2</div>
    <div class="example1">3</div>
    <div class="example1">4</div>
    <div class="example1">5</div>
    <div class="example1">6</div>
    <div class="example1">7</div>
    <div class="example1">8</div>
    <div class="example1">9</div>
    <div class="example1">10</div>
    <div class="example1">11</div>
    <div class="example1">12</div>
    <div class="example1">12</div>
    <div class="example1">13</div>
<div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
Now flex center, when you hide it makes rude effect, it isnt like div.example1:
<div class="second">
    <div class="example2">1</div>
    <div class="example2">2</div>
    <div class="example2">3</div>
    <div class="example2">4</div>
    <div class="example2">5</div>
    <div class="example2">6</div>
    <div class="example2">7</div>
    <div class="example2">8</div>
    <div class="example2">9</div>
    <div class="example2">10</div>
    <div class="example2">11</div>
    <div class="example2">12</div>
    <div class="example2">13</div>
    <div class="example2">14</div>
</div>
</div>
```